# Can a constexpr class template literal type be parameterized on a non-literal type?

Tags: c++, class, gcc, constexpr

I am playing around with an ORM design using gcc 4.9.2. I have a class of 2 members:

```
class Staff : public Db::TableBase<Staff> {
public:
    long int staffId_;
    std::string nickname_;
}
```

(TableBase is a class I use to pull in several static functions and subclass declarations into class scope. It has no members or methods, only static functions and subclass declarations.)

I have have a ColumnObject for each member:

```
static constexpr auto colTest1=Db::detail::ColumnObject<Staff,long int>
    (&Staff::staffId_,"staff_id",Db::BigSerial | Db::Default,Db::Transport::TEXT);
static constexpr auto colTest2=Db::detail::ColumnObject<Staff, std::basic_string<char> >
    (&Staff::nickname_,"nick_name",Db::NotNull,Db::Transport::TEXT);
```

The first statement compiles, the second does not:

```
~/git/WebSchedule2/src/common/ORM/Staff.hpp:110:152: error: ‘const Db::detail::ColumnObject<Staff, std::basic_string<char> >{&Staff::nickname_, ((const char*)"nick_name"), 1, (Db::Transport)0, -1}’ is not a constant expression
static constexpr auto colTest2=Db::detail::ColumnObject<Staff, std::basic_string<char> >(&Staff::nickname_,"nick_name",Db::NotNull,Db::Transport::TEXT);
```

You might say that the reason the second statement doesn't compile is because the type dependency on std::string makes it a non-literal. However, I don't actually use a string in the definition of ColumnObject, I only use the type information.The definition of ColumnObject:

```
template<typename Derived,typename MemberType>
class ColumnObject {
public:
    MemberType Derived::*memberPtr_;
    char const *columnName_;
    int const traits_;
    Db::Transport transport_;
    int columnNumber_;

    constexpr ColumnObject()
        : memberPtr_(nullptr), columnName_("UNITIALIZED COLUMN"), traits_(-1), 
            transport_(Db::Transport::TEXT), columnNumber_(-1) { }

    constexpr ColumnObject(MemberType Derived::*memberPtr, char const *columnName,
        int const traits, Db::Transport transport)
        : memberPtr_(memberPtr), columnName_(columnName), traits_(traits),
            transport_(transport), columnNumber_(-1) { }
}
```

Any ideas how I can work around this?

(Edit: I am including a complete example below. The problem seems to be using static constexprs.)

```
// g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++14 -c foo.cpp
#include <string>

template<typename Derived,typename MemberType>
class ColumnObject;

template<typename Derived,typename MemberType>
class ColumnObject {
public:
    MemberType Derived::*memberPtr_;
    char const *columnName_;

    constexpr ColumnObject()
        : memberPtr_(nullptr), columnName_("UNITIALIZED COLUMN") { }

    constexpr ColumnObject(MemberType Derived::*memberPtr, const char *columnName)
        : memberPtr_(memberPtr), columnName_(columnName) { }
};

class Staff {
public:
    long int staffId_;
    std::string nickname_;

    Staff(){
        staffId_=0;
        nickname_="";
    }

    Staff(long int snid, std::string nname)
        : staffId_(snid), nickname_(nname)
    {
    };

    static constexpr auto colTest1=ColumnObject<Staff,long int>(&Staff::staffId_,"staff_id");
    static constexpr auto colTest2=ColumnObject<Staff, std::string >(&Staff::nickname_,"nick_name");
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    constexpr auto colTest3=ColumnObject<Staff,long int>(&Staff::staffId_,"staff_id");
    constexpr auto colTest4=ColumnObject<Staff, std::string >(&Staff::nickname_,"nick_name");
}
```

Comment: working fine here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b540beaa39e323b0

Comment: The problem seems to be in the static constexpr. I have edited my original code to a complete, self-contained example.

Comment: working fine here, on clang :) -> http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9a3102e4849b0d0

Comment: This now works in RedHat gcc 5.3.1-2.

Answer (score 0):

working fine here, on clang :) -> [coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9a3102e4849b0d0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9a3102e4849b0d0) – pepper_chico

This now works in RedHat gcc 5.3.1-2. – user2352497